# Changing the color and text of the status message seen when starting and stopping a service in RHEL 6.4?

Tags: rhel, colors, services

How to change the color and text of the message while you start or stop a service?

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: it may vary depending on OS and/or initialization system (sys V init vs systemd ). Consider narrowing  your query by specifying your OS and version

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS 6.10 the following file contains the color configuration for SETCOLOR_SUCCESS, SETCOLOR_FAILURE, ...

```
/etc/sysconfig/init
```

Example:

```
# color => new RH6.0 bootup
# verbose => old-style bootup
# anything else => new style bootup without ANSI colors or positioning
BOOTUP=color
# column to start "[  OK  ]" label in 
RES_COL=60
# terminal sequence to move to that column. You could change this
# to something like "tput hpa ${RES_COL}" if your terminal supports it
MOVE_TO_COL="echo -en \\033[${RES_COL}G"
# terminal sequence to set color to a 'success' color (currently: green)
SETCOLOR_SUCCESS="echo -en \\033[0;32m"
# terminal sequence to set color to a 'failure' color (currently: red)
SETCOLOR_FAILURE="echo -en \\033[0;31m"
# terminal sequence to set color to a 'warning' color (currently: yellow)
SETCOLOR_WARNING="echo -en \\033[0;33m"
# terminal sequence to reset to the default color.
SETCOLOR_NORMAL="echo -en \\033[0;39m"
```

Maybe you can use the information and names to find the correct files on your system :)

Answer (score 1):

These definitions are in `/etc/init.d/functions`.

That script attempts to source in `/etc/sysconfig/init`, which contains the pertinent color definitions:

```
SETCOLOR_SUCCESS="echo -en \\033[0;32m"
SETCOLOR_FAILURE="echo -en \\033[0;31m"
SETCOLOR_WARNING="echo -en \\033[0;33m"
SETCOLOR_NORMAL="echo -en \\033[0;39m"
```

... while the original `/etc/init.d/functions` file defines functions for the various status messages, for example:

```
echo_success() {
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $MOVE_TO_COL
  echo -n "["
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $SETCOLOR_SUCCESS
  echo -n $"  OK  "
  [ "$BOOTUP" = "color" ] && $SETCOLOR_NORMAL
  echo -n "]"
  echo -ne "\r"
  return 0
}
```

... so if you wanted to emit something instead of `OK`, you'd edit that `echo` statement, and if you wanted to change the colors, you'd edit the corresponding definitions in `/etc/sysconfig/init`; if you do not have that file, note that the `functions` script will define the colors itself (in the `else` clause where it tests for the existence of the `init` file).